# Scrolling through pages with Python Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a python script that aims to take data off a website but I am unable to navigate and loop through pages to collect the links. The website is https://www.shearman.com/people? The Xpath on the site looks like this below;

- `ul class="results-pagination`"
- `li class/a href onclick="PageRequest('2', event)`"

When I run the query below is says that the element is not attached to the page;

```
 try:
        # this is navigate to next page
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="results-pagination"]/li/[@onclick=">"]').click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except NoSuchElementException:
       break
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong on this?

Many thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **code** :

```
browser.get("https://www.shearman.com/people")  

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30) 
main_tab = browser.current_window_handle

navigation_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="results-pagination"]//descendant::a')
size = len(navigation_buttons )
print ('this the length of list:',navigation_buttons )  

i = 0 
while i<size:
 ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(navigation_buttons [i]).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform() 
 browser.switch_to_window(main_tab)
 i=i+1;
 if i >= size:
  break
```

Make sure to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Note this will open each link in new tab. As per your requirement you can click on next button using this xpath :  `//ul[@class="results-pagination"]//descendant::a`

If you want to open links one by one in same tab , then you will have to handle stale element reference as once you will be moved out from main page , all element will become **stale**.